# The PVC is stuck in a pending state in the Azure OpenShift cluster

Tags: openshift, azure-file-share, aro

After provisioning an OpenShift cluster using the steps outlined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/openshift/tutorial-create-cluster and successfully deploying my application, I attempted to set up an Azure Files storage class as per the instructions provided in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/openshift/howto-create-a-storageclass. Although the storage class was created without any issues, the PVC remains stuck in a pending state when I attempt to create it.

This is my storage class definition

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azure-file
provisioner: file.csi.azure.com
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=0
  - gid=0
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict
  - actimeo=30
  - noperm
parameters:
  location: westeurope
  skuName: Standard_LRS
  storageAccount: <storage-account-name?
  resourceGroup: <rg-name>
  secretNamespace: kube-system // also tried with my custom namespace
  secretName: azure-storage-creds
  server: <storage-account>.file.core.windows.net
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

This is my PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: storage-test
  namespace: test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  volumeName: test-pv
  storageClassName: azure-file
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

Following the documentation, a secret should have been created after setting up the storage class but its not created and the PVC is still stuck in Pending state. When I describe my PVC, it doesn't show any events

```
kubectl -n uipath describe pvc asrobots-test
Name:          storage-test
Namespace:     test
StorageClass:  azure-file
Status:        Pending
Volume:        test-pv
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      0
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:        <none>
```

Comment: Is there any pod to use the PVC which you created? In general, the field volumeBindingMode in Storage class is set to waitforfirstconsumer mode. So if you haven't deployed any pod with the PVC, PV was not deployed unless a Pod use the PVC.

Comment: apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: storage-test
  namespace: test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  volumeName: test-pv
  storageClassName: azure-file
  volumeMode: Filesystem

• Any reason for specifying the volume name and mode? Have you tried without these?
• Curious know why you are using RWO with Azure Files.